# JBoss EAP 7.0 Externalized HTTP Sessions to JBoss Data Grid not working

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

I have followed the [configuration guide for JBoss EAP 7.0 - 21.3.7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0/configuration-guide/chapter-21-configuring-high-availability#externalize-http-sessions-to-jdg) to set up externalized HttpSessions to JDG

The steps are pretty simple, my standalone.xml has:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">
    <cache-container name="cacheContainer" default-cache="default-cache" module="org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan" statistics-enabled="true">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <replicated-cache name="default-cache" mode="SYNC">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            <remote-store cache="default" socket-timeout="60000" remote-servers="remote-jdg-server1 remote-jdg-server2" passivation="false" preload="true" purge="false" shared="true"/>
        </replicated-cache>
    </cache-container>
...
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-jdg-server1">
        <remote-destination host="jdbserver1" port="11222"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-jdg-server2">
        <remote-destination host="jdgserver2" port="11222"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
```

Then I added a jboss-web.xml file to my application's WEB-INF folder, referencing the cache container and the remote store cache:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd"
           version="10.0">
    <context-root>/myapp</context-root>
    <replication-config>
        <cache-name>cacheContainer.default-cache</cache-name>
        <replication-granularity>SESSION</replication-granularity>
    </replication-config>
</jboss-web>
```

However it doesn't seem to be working. I tested putting an attribute in session and restarting the server. Then I can see that it creates a new httpsession, not reusing the previous one and thus, missing the parameter set before. The logs don't show anything relevant.